# How to pass return statement value to another java class

Tags: java

In a package I am having two classes. My GetParameterValue.java return a session_id. And I  need to print that session_id in my IVRTest.java

**My GetParameterValue.java**

```
package com.raos.ivr;

import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;


public class GetParameterValue
{

    public static String conferenceurlmoderator(String responseString) throws JSONException
    {
        String url_moderator = responseString;
        String response_string_moderatorvalue = JSONConverter.passbymoderatorvalue(url_moderator);
        JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(response_string_moderatorvalue);

        JSONObject message_m = (JSONObject) jsonObj.get("response");
        long message1 = (long) message_m.get("message");
        String session_id_moderator = String.valueOf(message1);
        System.out.println("session_id_moderator = " + session_id_moderator);
        return session_id_moderator;

    }
    public static String conferenceurlparticipant(String responseString1) throws JSONException
    {
        String url_participant = responseString1;
        String response_string_participantvalue = JSONConverter.passbyparticipantvalue(url_participant);
        JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(response_string_participantvalue);

        JSONObject message_p = (JSONObject) jsonObj.get("response");
        long message2 = (long) message_p.get("message");
        String session_id_participant = String.valueOf(message2);  
        System.out.println("session_id_participant = " + session_id_participant);
        return session_id_participant;

    }

}
```

My **IVRTest.java**

```
package com.raos.ivr;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import org.json.JSONException;

import com.gpzhibernate.DBCommonOpertion;
import com.raos.ConferenceAPICall;
import com.raos.ivr.GetParameterValue;
import com.raos.KookooAPICall;
import com.raos.KookooAPISms;
import com.raos.tables.UserTable;
import com.raos.utils.DBConnect;  

public class IVRTest
{

    public static void main(String[] args) throws JSONException
    {
        String responseString = null;
        String[] Moderator_name_array = {"kalai"};
        String[] Participant_name_array = {"sundaresan"};
        String caller_id = "918030";
        String message_text = "Hi";
        String conference_id = "11223";
        String request = "conferencecall";

        DBConnect dbConnect = new DBConnect();
        boolean connectionStatus = dbConnect.establishConnection();
        System.out.println("Connection Status:" + connectionStatus);

        if (connectionStatus == true)
        {
            System.out.println("Connected");
            ArrayList<String> Moderator_number = getUserTableList(Moderator_name_array);
            System.out.println("Function call result:" + Moderator_number);
            ArrayList<String> Participant_number = getUserTableList(Participant_name_array);
            System.out.println("Function call result:" + Participant_number);

            if (request == "conferencecall")
            {
                System.out.println("conferencecall");
                String call_output =  ConferenceAPICall.ConferenceAPICallconnect(Moderator_number,Participant_number, caller_id, conference_id);
                GetParameterValue value = new GetParameterValue();
                String session_id_moderatorvalue = GetParameterValue.conferenceurlmoderator(responseString);
                System.out.println(session_id_moderatorvalue);
                String send_values = InsertValues.Conferencevalues(Moderator_number, conference_id, Participant_number, caller_id);
            }

        }
    }   
}
```

`

I am getting **output** as

`

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at java.io.StringReader.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at org.json.JSONTokener.<init>(JSONTokener.java:83)
    at org.json.XMLTokener.<init>(XMLTokener.java:55)
    at org.json.XML.toJSONObject(XML.java:367)
    at com.raos.ivr.JSONConverter.passbymoderatorvalue(JSONConverter.java:17)
    at com.raos.ivr.GetParameterValue.conferenceurlmoderator(GetParameterValue.java:13)
    at com.raos.ivr.IVRTest.main(IVRTest.java:61)`
```

Please help me how to pass a return value

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion is to declare sessionId variable as Static type in IVRTest